# how to loop over the tables of a database?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to loop over the tables of a database using the following code getting an error `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`. i have even tried with `cfloop query and other attributes` got errors complex value can't convert to simple value. can anyone tell me how shall i have to loop over this query ? Thanks.

```
<cfquery name="q" datasource="datasource">
    SHOW TABLES FROM datasource
</cfquery>
<cfloop collection ="#q#" item="i">
   #q[i]#
</cfloop>
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL? Have you tried just dumping the query? Does it return anything?

Comment: @SeanCoyne - I am using MySQL i did dump it, it shows all the table names...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting that error because cfloop `collection` expects a structure, not a query object. Hence the "UnsupportedOperation..." error.

Instead you should use a query loop. The generated column name is dynamic, based on the database name you supply. You can either hard code it or access it dynamically:

```
   <cfset colNames = listToArray(q.columnList)>
   <cfoutput query="q">
      <cfloop array="#colName#" index="col">
            #q[col][currentRow]#
      </cfloop>
      <br>
   </cfoutput>
```

That said, I find it easier to use the [metadata `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html). You can query them just like any table. Then output the static column names as usual.

```
    <cfquery name="yourQueryName" ...>
       SELECT  TABLE_NAME
       FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
       WHERE   TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YourDatabaseName'
    </cfquery>

    <cfoutput query="yourQueryName">
         #TABLE_NAME# <br>
    </cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thanks Leigh... this is really awesome answer. can you tell me how can we get the column names of all the tables ?

Comment: Query the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html) view instead. To get the columns for a single table, just filter on the `TABLE_NAME` instead of schema. ie `...WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Some Table'`

Comment: Actually, I take that back. You should Filter on *both* `table_name` and `table_schema`. Just in case the same `table_name` exists in multiple databases.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this too helpful.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried [CFDBINFO](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7685.html)? It supports a type of 'tabes' and ought to return you a query of table name, type and remarks for each table.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
<cfoutput query="q">
#tables#
<cfoutput>
```

Comment: tables are in tables_in_database column.... its not working. when i dump it i didn't find any column name except tables_in_nameofdb.